# POWA analyzer displays error 500 after logging in

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I tried to install [POWA](https://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) web analyzer. I can see the login page but after login there is a 500 error message.

This is the error at the server:

```sql
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for table powa_servers
    
    [SQL: SELECT
           CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN
              '<local>'
           ELSE
              COALESCE(alias, hostname || ':' || port)
           END AS alias,
            error
            FROM powa_servers s
            JOIN (SELECT srvid, unnest(errors) error
                FROM powa_snapshot_metas
                WHERE errors IS NOT NULL
            ) m ON m.srvid = s.id]
    (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

I granted all permissions to `powa` user in postgres and loggin in using this user.

Answer (score 0):

There are additional requirements for database objects documented at https://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html.

Let me know if there are any problems after applying those.

Comment: You may want to add salient points from your link to the answer itself, lest it becomes useless when the link goes stale.